# High quality charts in python / django

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice draw. There charts are simply superb. I want to create charts of a comparable quality (high, in my opinion) in my web application using django.

Most of the developers recommend matplotlib, but I don't want to go with that because I need chart of type bar, line, pie, area. Can anyone suggest chart library in python/django.

Or, if a solution other than python/django can generate high quality chart (including 3D) please propose it.

Comment: You said you didn't want to use matplotlib because of all the different chart types needed, but have you checked out the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html)?  There are some javascript alternatives too like Flot and Graphael.

Comment: Have you considered doing that in the front end using something like [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) and using Django just to shift the data out to the end user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with jvc26's comment, [d3](http://d3js.org/) is a good option. I also recommend [nvd3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nvd3/) - a python module designed specifically for using D3 with django.

Comment: thanks for your recommendations sir. I'm using nvd3, I'll take a look for d3

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple (at least I think it is simple) python library for images on a 2d coordinate system. You may want to give it a try, it is hosted on github -- [cartesius](http://tkrajina.github.com/cartesius/). Here are a few examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is good, but I'm expecting a lot more in color representation, graphics, appearance
thanks a lot and thanks in advance